# C3P0 Configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm confused on when to use a standalone C3P0 specific config file such as `c3p0-config.xml` vs simply adding configuration information to the standard Context.xml file. For example:

```
<Resource auth="Container"
          description="DB Connection"
          driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          maxPoolSize="1000"
          minPoolSize="30"
          acquireIncrement="1"
          name="jdbc/myDB"
          user="myUserName"
          password="myPassword"
          factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
          type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB?autoReconnect=false"
          preferredTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
          idleConnectionTestPeriod = "1800" 
/>
```

I currently use the context.xml approach but I see documentation for a completely separate config file. Is there a correct way or a trade off for choosing either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c3p0 is not, in general, used just with Tomcat. but within Tomcat, the approach that you are taking should work fine. there are some [library-wide (rather than DataSource-specific) properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0-0.9.5-pre4/#other-properties) that can only be set in a c3p0.properties or typesafe/HOCON config file, but those are rarely used. as long as all you need to configure are DataSource-specific properties, you can keep doing what you are doing.